# JavaScript Barcode detection API returning undefined for rawData

Tags: javascript, canvas, undefined, barcode-scanner, webapi

I would like to integrate a feature to my website which can detect QR codes. So for that, I had used **Barcode Detection API**. But it is returning *undefined* for `rawData`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
<video id="bar" autoplay style="width:100vw;height:100vh;margin:0;object-fit:cover;"></video>
<canvas id="canvas1" hidden></canvas>
<img id="input" hidden/>
```

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: 0,
    video: {
        facingMode: {
            exact: "environment"
        }
    }
}).then(s => {
    const bar = document.getElementById('bar');
    bar.srcObject = s;
    bar.onloadedmetadata = () => {
        setInterval(() => {
            const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
            canvas.width = bar.videoWidth;
            canvas.height = bar.videoHeight;
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(bar, 0, 0);
            const input = document.getElementById('input');
            input.src = canvas.toDataURL();
            if ('BarcodeDetector' in window) {
                const detector = new BarcodeDetector();
                detector.detect(input).then(detections => {
                    detections.forEach(detected => {
                        alert(detected.rawData)
                    })
                })
            }
        }, -1)
    }
});
```

[image: Output of Barcode Detection API]

Here is the **demo**: https://authentication-demo.000webhostapp.com/

**EDIT**
Issue is resolved. I had simply changed to `rawValue` from `rawData`.
`alert(detected.rawValue||detected.rawData);`

Comment: what else is in `detected` object - hint: use `console.log` and check the log for the object contents - the demo errors with "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The object can not be found here."

Comment: Sorry, I'm working on mobile. Here is the URL to the live demo https://authentication-demo.000webhostapp.com/. Please open console and verify in your browser.

Comment: oh, right - this is a chrome only thing at the moment ... what about `detected.format` - what does that result in

Comment: ```detected.format``` returning perfectly. When I scanned a QR code, it returned ```qr_code```. But returning ```rawData``` as ```undefined```.

Comment: But I don't want what type of code it was, I mean format. I want to acces the data of the scanned code

Comment: I just wanted to know if it was detecting a barcode - according to caniuse it's only just been added to Android Chrome in the latest version - knowing google, it's as buggy as a Tarsier

Comment: try `alert(Object.keys(detected))` to see what properties detected actually has

Comment: @Bravo Thanks for your suggestion. Alredy tried your solution just right before your comment. I just don't know why in MDN, they had used ```rawData```. The code works perfectly when changed that ```rawData``` to ```rawValue```. But for cross-browser compatibility purpose I used ```alert(detected.rawValue||detected.rawData);```. Anyhow thanks for your suggestion. Hurray, finally it's working! 

Comment: it's a experimental API, subject to change, only available in Chrome, so don't expect Mozilla to care about the accuracy of its docs

Answer (score -1):

just add breakpoint on result variable.
in this case is detected.

so you can use the required data as you wish.

Ex:

```
detected.rawValue
```